# Creating Bootstrap-Datepicker with multiple asp:Repeater TextBoxes

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating form using an asp:Repeater, each object of the repeater has one textbox that will need it's own unique bootstrap-datepicker linked to it. (the datepicker is a javascript addon to twitter-bootstrap 2.3.2 found here: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker -- Wanted to add that the link is safe, but there is no real need to view the page in regards to the question)

My problem is that I am not able to use the asp.net clientid to correctly target the text boxes.

aspx code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repList" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul class="gridul">
            <li class="gridli userrole"><span class="short liheader">Jenz ID</span></li>
            <li class="gridli"><span class="long liheader">Name</span></li>
            <li class="gridli"><span class="short liheader">S/S/F</span></li>
            <li class="gridli"><span class="short liheader">Date</span></li>
            <li class="gridli"><span class="long liheader">Payment Type</span></li>
            <li class="gridli"><span class="mid liheader">Sent to B.O.</span></li>
        </ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <ul class="gridul">
            <li class="gridli userrole"><span class="short"><%# Eval("jenzabar_id") %></span></li>
            <li class="gridli"><span class="long"><%# Eval("first_name") %>&nbsp<%# Eval("last_name") %></span></li>
            <li class="gridli"><span class="short"><%# Eval("student_staff_faculty") %></span></li>
            <li class="gridli"><span class="short"><%# Eval("reservation_date") %></span></li>
            <li class="gridli"><span class="long"><asp:TextBox ID="PayType" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("payment_type") %>' /></span></li>
            <li class="gridli"><span class="mid"><asp:TextBox ID="SentBo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sent_to_bo") %>' /></span></li>
        </ul>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidJenz" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("jenzabar_id") %>' />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidPayType" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("payment_type") %>' />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidSentBo" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("sent_to_bo") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The textbox being targeted is:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="SentBo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sent_to_bo") %>' />
```

In my scripts.js I can target an individual textbox by viewing the aspx source and copying in the generated id such as "ctl00_MainContent_repList_ctl01_SentBo" but I cannot figure out how to use <%# SentBo.ClientID %> with the repeater.  It just doesn't work.

Example:

```
$(function () {
    $('ctl00_MainContent_repList_ctl01_SentBo').datepicker();
})
```

is successful

```
$(function () {
    $('<%#= SentBo.ClientID %>').datepicker();
})
```

is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did more digging.  Found the answer, finally.

Replace:

```
$('ctl00_MainContent_repList_ctl01_SentBo').datepicker();
```

with:

```
$(this).find("input[type=text][id*=SentBo]").datepicker();
```